# Creating a plot with multiple variables and multiple plots next to each other

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hello all I have a data frame that looks like this

```
   vcv.index model.index par.index grid index  estimate         se       lcl       ucl fixed Primary Sex
1          6           6        16    A    16 0.8856129 0.07034495 0.6650065 0.9679442             1   F
2          7           7        17    A    17 0.6298085 0.06925362 0.4873071 0.7527946             2   F
3          8           8        18    A    18 0.6299329 0.06658399 0.4930294 0.7487096             3   F
4          9           9        19    A    19 0.6298073 0.05511803 0.5170043 0.7300226             4   F
5         10          10        20    A    20 0.7575780 0.05033492 0.6461752 0.8424570             5   F
6         21          21        61    B    61 0.8712803 0.07640191 0.6404038 0.9625845             1   F
7         22          22        62    B    62 0.6074361 0.06881164 0.4677850 0.7314780             2   F
8         23          23        63    B    63 0.6041038 0.06107390 0.4805314 0.7156737             3   F
9         24          24        64    B    64 0.5806663 0.06927518 0.4422311 0.7074705             4   F
10        25          25        65    B    65 0.7370924 0.05892159 0.6070616 0.8357368             5   F
11        41          41       121    C   121 0.8047651 0.09683670 0.5519029 0.9324112             1   F
12        42          42       122    C   122 0.5259543 0.07165185 0.3871407 0.6608688             2   F
13        43          43       123    C   123 0.5427102 0.07127190 0.4033297 0.6757102             3   F
14        44          44       124    C   124 0.5168940 0.06156377 0.3975699 0.6343222             4   F
15        45          45       125    C   125 0.6550035 0.07378427 0.5002863 0.7826314             5   F
16       196         196       586    A   586 0.8535576 0.08711021 0.5979391 0.9580602             1   M
17       197         197       587    A   587 0.5672181 0.07079460 0.4268475 0.6975683             2   M
18       198         198       588    A   588 0.5675404 0.06380437 0.4408554 0.6859682             3   M
19       199         199       589    A   589 0.5666988 0.06499677 0.4377245 0.6872281             4   M
20       200         200       590    A   590 0.7058527 0.05985742 0.5769525 0.8085129             5   M
21       211         211       631    B   631 0.8359801 0.09415382 0.5702268 0.9514068             1   M
22       212         212       632    B   632 0.5432876 0.07906137 0.3891407 0.6895670             2   M
23       213         213       633    B   633 0.5401000 0.06497578 0.4129088 0.6622738             3   M
24       214         214       634    B   634 0.5161817 0.06292617 0.3943413 0.6361283             4   M
25       215         215       635    B   635 0.6821666 0.07279913 0.5263900 0.8056259             5   M
26       226         226       676    C   676 0.7620894 0.10484134 0.5077061 0.9086707             1   M
27       227         227       677    C   677 0.4607459 0.07326857 0.3240289 0.6036357             2   M
28       228         228       678    C   678 0.4775193 0.08336355 0.3219411 0.6375852             3   M
29       229         229       679    C   679 0.4517796 0.06392891 0.3319493 0.5774748             4   M
30       230         230       680    C   680 0.5944339 0.07210424 0.4492079 0.7248249             5   M
```

I am trying to create a plot(s) that has the Primary along the X-axis and estimate on the Y-axix with one line for each of the Sex (M,F). Then I would want to make a total of 3 of these graphs each sorted by the grid (A,B, C). Then combine each of these into one figure. So it be a comparison of three plots by estimates and primary. I am getting some horribly wrong plots when I try to make it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(your_dataframe, aes(x=Primary, y=estimate, col=Sex)) + 
geom_line() + 
facet_wrap(~ grid)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, Thank you! I was definitely trying to make things more complex than they needed to be